Does anyone know how to decode the following data?
Does anyone know how to decode the following data?
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9Y^^,d,\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00Ydd,\x89,\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9Y^\x92,^,\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9Ydd,\x89,\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00z\x97\x89,\x89,\x00\x00\x00'

”Situation”
Those data is coming from bill accepter. I connected a bill accepter to my raspberry pi via RS232 to acquire data.(I try to develop mini-vending machine for my family business)
I was able to get data from this bill accepter, but I don't know how to decode it.　I have used every decoder I can think of for now, but none of them worked.
Those data should include "20", because I insert 20thb(Thailand bath) bill into the bill accepter for the test. Bill accepter name is [genius 7], and there is no info about receiving data in the manual(they provide only manual for wiring...).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I stack here for 4 days;)
**”python_code” **
import serial
import struct
import chardet

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            line0 = ser.readline()
            line1 = line0.replace(b'\x00', b'')
            line2 = line1.decode("cp1252")
            #line3 = line1.decode("utf-16le")
            
            result = chardet.detect(line0)
            
            print(line0)
            #print(line1)
            print(line2)
            #print(line3)
            print(result)

I try to detect the encoder with "chardet", and it says encoder is windows-1252.
so I tried, but the result is here.....
I thought it is utf-16le, but it also don't work.
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11\x97d\x89,\x89,\x00\x00\x00'
—d‰,‰,
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9Ydd,d,\x00\x00\x00'
ùYdd,d,
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-9', 'confidence': 0.4122478846530419, 'language': 'Turkish'}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11Yd\x89,\x89,\x00\x00\x00'
Yd‰,‰,
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9\x97d/\xec,^,\x00\x00\x00'
ù—d/ì,^,
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11Ydd,^,\x00\x00\x00'
Ydd,^,
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11\xdfd/^,d,\x00\x00\x00'
ßd/^,d,
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11Y^d,^,\x00\x00\x00'
Y^d,^,
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9\x97d/d,d,\x00\x00\x00'
ù—d/d,d,
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11\x97d/d|^,\x00\x00\x00'
—d/d|^,
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11Y^d,^,\x00\x00\x00'
Y^d,^,
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9\x97\x89,\x89\x9c\x00\x00\x00'
ù—‰,‰œ
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9\x97\x89,\x89\x9c\x00\x00\x00'
ù—‰,‰œ
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
b'\x00\x00\x00\xf9Y\x89,\x89\xc9\x00\x00\x00'
ùY‰,‰É
{'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0, 'language': None}
b'\x00\x00\x00\x11\x97\x89,\x89\x9c\x00\x00\x00'
—‰,‰œ
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}


There is no guarantee that this data is encoded text. It's likely to be a proprietary binary format, which we can't help you with unless you can provide details of the format.

I found a manual for some variant of Genius 7 which suggests there should be a DIP switch to select which protocol it talks. One of the options is ccTalk which seems to have decent documentation available.

Assuming that since you are using serial you are trying to do MDB. The MDB protocol is 9 bit not 8 so you need to account for that. Go out to the NAMA website and download the MDB protocol guide. Will show you all the communications you can do with any MDB device.
